# EL expression of JSF in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsf

I am getting error using value of El expression:

> Error Traced[line: 166] Element type "h:inputFile" must be followed by
>   either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

How to bind the array of bean to dynamically generated `<input type="file"/>` using JavaScript?

view page code

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
</div>
```

Code JavaScript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var _validFileExtensions = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".bmp", ".gif", ".png", ".pdf", ".doc", ".docx"];
    function ValidateSingleInput(oInput) {
        if (oInput.type == "file") {
            var sFileName = oInput.value;

            if (sFileName.length > 0) {
                var blnValid = false;
                for (var j = 0; j < _validFileExtensions.length; j++) {
                    var sCurExtension = _validFileExtensions[j];
                    if (sFileName.substr(sFileName.length - sCurExtension.length, sCurExtension.length).toLowerCase() == sCurExtension.toLowerCase()) {
                        blnValid = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!blnValid) {
                    alert("Sorry, File Extension  is invalid, allowed extensions are: " + _validFileExtensions.join(", "));
                    oInput.value = "";
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    $("document").ready(function () {
        var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
        var x = 1; //initlal text box count
        var i = 0;

        $(add_button).click(function (e) { //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            if (x & lt; max_fields){ //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box increment
                $(wrapper).append('<div><h:inputFile id="attachment" styleClass="file" name="myfile[]" value="#{mofNewBean.attachmentFiles["' +  i +'"]}" onchange="ValidateSingleInput(this);" /><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
                i++;
                alert(#{mofNewBean.attachmentFiles[i]});
                alert(i);
            }
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) { //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            x--;
        });
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```

mof bean:

```
private Part[] attachmentFiles;

public Part[] getAttachmentFiles() {
    return attachmentFiles;
}

public void setAttachmentFiles(Part[] attachmentFiles) {
    this.attachmentFiles = attachmentFiles;
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    attachmentFiles=new Part[10];
}
```

Comment: add on your script `//<![CDATA[` one line before your script and `//]]>` one line after

Comment: after intrigating  //<![CDATA[ one line before your script and //]]>  the javascript code is not  working.

Comment: Well, there must be some error on it then. Check your browser developer tools to see it.

Comment: its working now but need help to bind the value of input type file to bean array  .i.e mofNewBean.attachmentFiles[i] is  not working code is if(x < max_fields){ 
               x++; 
               $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="file" id="attachment" styleClass="file" name="myfile[]" value="#{mofNewBean.attachmentFiles[i]}" onchange="ValidateSingleInput(this);" /><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
           i++;

Comment: Well I don't think you can add jsf tags from a javascript. It is processed on the server. This will not work.

Comment: can help me to use jquery ajax to call back end to bind input type file value

Comment: I would say that you need a bit more complicated code to solve your problem. You may have to use `c` tags to generate that input from your jsp/xhtml or even ui:repeat I can't be more specific on that based on the piece of code you gave.

Comment: i have a jsf view page code

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by appending `<h:inputFile>` to `<div class="input_fields_wrap">` using JavaScript? `<h:inputFile>` is not an HTML element which is going to be interpreted by browsers unless / until it is parsed and its generated corresponding HTML is sent to browsers as a response by the JSF framework.

Comment: I want to  give  multiple file choosing option  by appending  the JS   but the choosed  files are not binding with the <h:inputFIle value=#{mofNewBean.attachmentFiles[i]"}  .

Comment: Irrelevant to the error you got : If the JavaScript code somehow runs without any error, you will see `<h:inputFIle>` itself inside `<div class="input_fields_wrap">` in the generated HTML DOM tree which is wrong as it is not an HTML element which browsers have to interpret. You will need to prefer another way depending upon the requirement (which I am completely unaware of).